# Service worker installation in Headless Chrome (via puppeteer)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I have a service worker that is registered with

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.bundle.js').then(registration => {
        console.log('Service worker was registered');
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('Registration failed: ', error);
    });
}
```

The actual service worker is logging its `install` and `activate` events with regular console.log() calls, all of this is working as expected.

However, when it came to the testing automation, the **Headless Chrome / puppeteer** solution is not working as it was expected, the service worker is not `installed` (the install event does not happen). So, the question is, is there any special way of testing pages with service workers with **Headless Chrome / puppeteer**?

The **puppeteer** code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox']});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.on('console', msg => console.log('PAGE LOG:', msg.text()));

  await page.goto('https://***.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
  await page.waitFor(1*4000);
  console.log('Before reload');
  await page.reload({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
  await page.screenshot({path: 'public/vidi.png'});
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Links:

- [GitHub issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2469)
- [Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)
- [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)
- [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/ServiceWorker#method-disable)

Answer (score 3):

Yes,

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--enable-features=NetworkService'],
    headless: true,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
  });
```

--enable-features=NetworkService enables service worker (experimental) and ignoreHTTPSErrors is required to overcome the https requirement of service workers when in the puppeteer context (served over file:///)

Comment: Thanks. Question though: this is not working when set to `headless: false`, what might be the issue? See this issue: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/4129

Comment: if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {} control goes into into if block, but getting error while SW register() execution.